# Do I need to keep the Bitmap object when using Bitmap.GetHBITMAP()?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

When using `Bitmap.GetHBITMAP()`, do I need to keep (not delete) the `Bitmap` object, or does `Bitmap.GetHBITMAP()` creates a new `HBITMAP` and not just returns the one that the `Bitmap` object uses? (the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not mention anything about this).

Comment: No.  It creates a new GDI bitmap and returns its handle.  You must call DeleteObject() after you're done with it to release it again.

Comment: *"The Bitmap::GetHBITMAP method **creates**..."* create implies you need to destroy, but I agree the documentation could be more explicit.

Comment: I think he is asking if you need to keep the GDI+ Bitmap instance alive after creating an HBITMAP from it or not, not whether the HBITMAP needs to be destroyed or not.